# else if statement in Windows script

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to check few conditions using if else statement on Windows script. Here is the block of code.

```
if "%1" == "" (
echo empty
) else (
if %1 LSS 1900  (
echo lesser
) else (
if %1 GTR 1900 (
echo greater    
)))
```

I'm trying to echo these statement based on the argument passed. Greater and Lesser conditions are working. But when i dont pass any argument, I get error message on cmd "1900 was unexpected at this time." whereas expected echo is empty.

Please help me on this. If this is a repeated question kindly direct me to the answer. I searched internetand i'm helpless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `%1` then evaluates to an empty string and thus the line reads

```
if  LSS 1900  (
```

which is invalid syntax.

The problem here is that *everything* (because it's conceptually a single statement) is *parsed* at once, even the parts that are not run at all. One option would be to introduce a variable:

```
set ARG=0
if not "%1"=="" set "ARG=%1"

if "%1" == "" (
  echo empty
) else if %ARG% LSS 1900  (
  echo lesser
) else if %ARG% GTR 1900 (
  echo greater
)
```

Note also that the extra blocks are not strictly necessary, so I omitted them here for readability.

Comment: How do you properly do it then?

Comment: he's testing for empty strings on the first line `if "%1" == "" (`

Comment: @bastos.sergio: See my edit, it's irrelevant that they're testing for it because the error occurs *before* the code is even run.

Answer (score -2):

The above answer is incorrect. Yes, you should use else..if, but it isn't else if, it's elself in batch(Windows shell scripting)

```
SET /P name=
IF %name%=="John" (
     ECHO name is john.
) elself %name%!="John"(
     ECHO name isn't john
) else (
  ECHO Error!
)
```